# Ubuntu Ethernet cable not detected

Tags: networking, ethernet

My ethernet connection works fine in windows 8.1.
But in ubuntu 15.04 it does not detect the link

Here's the output of ethtool eth0:

```
Settings for eth0:
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 10Mb/s
Duplex: Half
Port: MII
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
               drv probe ifdown ifup
Link detected: no
```

As can be seen No link is detected though i have plugged in the ethernet cable.

And ifconfig eth0 up gives:

```
eht0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

Please help i don't understand what the problem is whether this is a driver issue or whatever.

**EDIT:**

output of lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:80dd]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

**EDIT 2:**

i also noticed that the lights which are supposed to be blinking in the laptop when the ethernet cable is plugged in is off. (But works fine in windows by the way).

**EDIT 3:**
I noticed that if i shutdown the computer and leave it for some 5 minutes everything goes back to normal. But if i restart the computer the problem persists.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Done question edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same ethernet controller and same problem.

It will work with:

```
sudo modprobe -v r8169
```

Make a test manually, and if it works fine add to rc.local to make it permanent:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/rc.local
```

And add

```
modprobe r8169
```

**before** `exit 0`

Save and exit.

Really this is a bug in 15.04 since kernel 3.19.0-25. Before this kernel (3.19.0-22) it worked perfectly.

Comment: I have run into the same problem again after upgrade to 16.04. This time modprobe does not give any output. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your module must be badly supported by the kernel `r8169` module.

Connect to internet using some other adapter and run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```